# R: read_fwf () multiple text files from folder then write csv files to same folder (i.e., convert folder of text files to folder of csv files)

Tags: r, csv, txt

From a single folder of space delimited text files I want to read the files in and then write them out as csv files to the same folder.

The space delimited text files are annoying with the second row being dashes and three rows at the end of each file with some incorrect summary values (see below). These were removed with "comment" and "skip" arguments in "read_fwf". If there is a better way to achieve this, please advise.

```
    Frame   Clusters   Total Area
    -----------------------------
        0          2          353   
        1          2          233   
        2          1           18   
        3          1           18 
      ...        ...         ... 
     6230          1           38   
     6231          2          183   

    Total qualifying frame count = 6105
    Total file cluster count     = 42005
    Total file biomass area      = 8867980
```

I am trying to use tidyverse options like lapply instead of coded loops.

I think I am reading in the text files okay. My failure seems to be in the write.csv part of the code.

As a new user of R, I would greatly appreciate any recommendations or links to syntax (i.e., parentheses, indents, etc.). And tips for clarity on forum posts would help too. Thank you.

```
    # Clear all variables
    rm(list = ls())

    # Reference tidyverse
    library(tidyverse)

    # Create variable, "folder" for location of text files
    folder <- "C:/Users/stai669/OneDrive - PNNL/Desktop/CRDC_P/DP/DIDSON snip 
    files/largeDataset/Cluster/Aft/N/"

    # Create variable, "file_list" that lists all files in folder for "lapply" to loop through
    filelist <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = "*.txt")

    # Read in each file with "lapply"; other arguments for column names, etc.
    data <- lapply(filelist, function(x) {
                      textfile <- read_fwf(
                      paste(folder, x, sep = ""),
                      fwf_positions(start = c(1, 6, 17), end = c(5, 16, 29),
                      comment = "T",
                      col_names = c("fram", "clust", "biom"),
                      skip = 2,
                      cols(fram = col_integer(), clust = col_integer(), biom =    col_integer())
                      )
    # Write the files to csv in the same folder                          
        write.csv(textfile, file = sub(pattern = "\\.txt$", replacement = ".csv", x = x))
        })
```

Comment: No backslashes. Try `x <- "myfile.txt"` and then `sub(".txt$", ".csv", x)`.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine except you need one extra closing bracket to `read_fwf` before `write.csv`

Comment: "col_names" is part of the "fwf_positions" argument. I had it separate. This fixed the code along with the missing closing bracket made clear by Ronak Shah. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a novice. Further comments are welcome as there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Clear all variables
rm(list = ls())

# Reference tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# Create variable, "file_list" that lists all files in folder for "lapply()" to loop through
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")

# Read in each file with "lapply"; other arguments for column names, etc.
data <- lapply(filelist, function(x) {
                          textfile <- read_fwf(
                          paste(x, sep = ""),
                          fwf_positions(start = c(1, 6, 17), end = c(5, 16, 29), col_names = c("fram", "clust", "biom")),
                          comment = "T",
                          skip = 2,
                          cols(fram = col_integer(), clust = col_integer(), biom = col_integer())
                          )
# Write the files as csv to the same folder                          
            write.csv(textfile, file = sub(pattern = "\\.txt$", replacement = ".csv", x = x))
})
```

Again, note that the "col_names" argument goes with the "fwf_positions".